# How to detect Premature ventricular contractions (PVCs) in a ECG-signal

Tags: python, ecg

I want to know how to detect a  Premature ventricular contraction (PVC) in a ECG-signal. A PVC is best seen from the V1-lead in an Electrocardiogram.

[image: PVC example]
***Figure 1:*** *A) PVC coming from the left ventricle, B) PVC coming from the right ventricle*

The definition of a PVC can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_ventricular_contraction)

Answer (score 1):

I'm an audio guy and not a biomed guy, but if the ECG is decently periodic except for an occasional artifact or anomaly like a PVC, you can do *"pitch detection"* (estimating the period or fundamental frequency) of the waveform and tune a comb filter to null out the periodic component.  Then the anomalies will be the only thing left after subtracting or nulling out the periodic component.

Then you can perhaps have a dictionary of waveshapes for possible anolamies and cross-correlate (sliding correlation) each of the waveshapes against this remaining waveform.  That operation is, essentially, what we call a *"matched filter"*, which is used to recognize *"grains"* of signals.